# Unable to call route through javascript function

Tags: javascript, laravel, routes

I am trying to call a laravel route through javascript function. I have explored all the way on internet and over here but I am not finding up my solution. I referred to one answer over stack overflow about how to call route in javascript function but it didn't work for me. My route:

`Route::get("edit_contact/{id}",'ContactController@edit');`

Javascript function:

```
    {
         var url = '{{ route("edit_contact",":id") }}';
         url = url.replace(':id', count);
         document.location.href = url;          
    }
```

count is defined up in javascript which I need to pass in route.
Issue is this that it is continuously giving error..
`Route [edit_contact] not defined.`

All these routes are working fine when hitting through html. I have also tried to call up other routes as well through this, but none is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your route like this:

```
Route::get("edit_contact/{id}",'ContactController@edit')->name('edit_contact');
```

Comment: O wao thanku.. I never thought that issue can be so trivial

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: If we have to pass one two variables in route through javascript, how it would be? I have tried to add it by ':b_id' but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
var routeUrl = route('posts.index');
var routeUrl = route('posts.show', {post: 1337});

// Returns results from /posts
return axios.get(route('posts.index'))
  .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
   });
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
let count=3
document.location.href = `edit_contact/${count}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this piece. it should work:

```
Route::get("edit_contact/{id}",'ContactController@edit');

javascript code

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#valueid").change(function(e){

       var id= e.target.value; // the id to be pass
        //alert(id);
        //checking the state of the domain if secured or not
           if ("https:" == document.location.protocol) {
            //alert('secured');
            location.href="https://www.example.com/edit_contact/"+id;
        } else {
            //alert('not secured');
             location.href="http://www.example.com/edit_contact/"+id;
        }

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In route file: (web.php)

```
Route::get("edit_contact/{id}",'ContactController@edit');
```

In js code:

Here I used count value 3 just for an example. You can use your actual value of count.

```
<script>
   var count = 3;

   var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

   var url = baseurl + '/edit_contact/' + count;            

   document.location.href = url; 

</script>
```